# Category and Product page CSS messing up each others pages

Tags: css, magento-1.9

I am facing a problem with my CSS setup for my category and product page in Magento. The category page has a width of 70% in the col-main part to make sure that the sidebar on the left shows up.

At the moment it doesn't and gets shown on the bottom of the page. This is because of the setting on the stylesheet `options_base_nl.css` is set towards 100% otherwise the product page will be shown with a width of 70%. This makes my product page look all weird and messed up.

The code for the col-main part in stylesheet `options_base_nl.css` is:

```
.col2-layout .sidebar  { width: 20.41%;}
.col2-layout .col-main { width: 100%;}
.col2-left-layout .col-main-wrap { margin-left: 30px;}
.col2-right-layout .col-main-wrap { margin-right: 300px;}
.col2-layout .col-main { width: 100%;}
.col2-layout .sidebar  { width: 245px;}
```

when I set the `.col2-layout .col-main {100%}` (the top one) on 70% it will let the sidebar come back towards the left side of the category but it will also mess up my product page.

How do I make sure my sidebar will come back on the category pages, but my product page has a 100% width?

Here are links towards a category and a product page:

Category: http://www.thefixedgearshop.com/nl/fixed-gear-fietsen/alle-fietsen

Product: http://www.thefixedgearshop.com/nl/fixed-gear-fietsen/alle-fietsen/6ku-bikes-fixed-gear-dallas-477

What am I overseeing? What am I doing wrong? I am searching in a back-up now but cant find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong layout for your detail page, if you what to have only one column on that page you should use the one column layout.

Comment: So i make sure the product page uses another col-main part? Which file is the one i need to change and where do i make this change?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the layout comment of @tribleb. What went wrong is the product view got a 2column layout as well in the local.xml file of the theme. This was edited by a plugin (FAQ) that i installed. This plugin changed a setting i think or blocked the view on the product page.